# Java JAR/dependency that runs code automatically under Spring Boot + Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I want to create Maven dependency that when you add it to a Maven project that is using Spring Boot, my dependency's package will automatically execute some code.

I really have no idea how to do this.  My guess was to try and create a bean and tag one of its methods with @PostConstruct.  This is not a requirement, it's just something I'm trying, so feel free to suggest an alternative.

Comment: You can check for loaded class using getClass().getClassloader().loadClass(springBootClassName) and catching any ClassNotFoundException. You would have to run this test on startup. With tomcat it can be done using a ServletContextListener.

Comment: The first things is by adding to execute some code would be dangerous apart from that you can add a dependency to a spring boot project which will turn on/off features when you start your application...see the spring boot documentation...